# Running a slow formula macro

Tags: performance, vba, excel

My macro works with a decent, but not an excessive amount of data ((<1000 rows with 5-10 columns). What is seemingly slowing down the macro are the two additional columns with formulas referencing the data, particularly with this code..

```
lastrow = cells(rows.count,7).end(xlup).row
for i = 5 to lastrow
cells(i,8).formular1c1 = "=100*ln(rc[-1]/r[-1])"
next i
for i = 22 to lastrow
cells(i,9).formuar1c1 = "=stdev(r[-20]c[-1]:rc[-1])*(251)^.5"
next i
```

I find that the macro with this piece brings about recurring lagging issues with excel. Does anybody here know a fix to this? Or provide some tips speeding up the macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use loop for it. Just apply formula to entire range:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

Range("H5:H" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=100*ln(rc[-1]/r[-1])"
Range("I22:I" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=stdev(r[-20]c[-1]:rc[-1])*(251)^.5"
```

and it's better to add little check of `lastrow`:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow >= 5 Then Range("H5:H" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=100*ln(rc[-1]/r[-1])"
If lastrow >= 22 Then Range("I22:I" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=stdev(r[-20]c[-1]:rc[-1])*(251)^.5"
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion. Worked like a charm! I didn't apply the check, can you briefly explain the purpose of it?

Comment: what would be if lastrow is 3? you would get a range `Range("H5:H3")` wich is equal to `Range("H3:H5")` and you can lost your data from `H3:H5`, because they would be rewritten with formula. The same thing with `Range("I22:I" & lastrow)` : for lastrow=3, it would rewrite all data from `Range("I3:I22")` with formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating some code logic which will make the execution faster. Formulas can sometimes put the execution on a toss.